# R select data that occurs before a certain date

Tags: r

So I have two datasets(tables) that look like this:

Dataset A:

```
Email   Date    Action
aaaa    1/5/14  won
bbbb    2/10/14 won
cccc    1/14/14 won
dddd    3/3/14  won
eeee    4/19/14 won
```

Dataset B:

```
Email   Date    Action
aaaa    1/5/14  won
aaaa    1/6/14  call
aaaa    1/9/14  email
aaaa    1/20/14 email
bbbb    2/8/14  email
bbbb    2/9/14  email
bbbb    2/10/14 won
bbbb    2/11/14 callback
bbbb    2/12/14 email
bbbb    2/13/14 won
cccc    1/14/14 won
cccc    1/16/14 call
dddd    2/3/14  email
dddd    3/3/14  won
eeee    4/19/14 won
eeee    4/21/14 call
```

I'd like it to look like this:

```
Email   Date    Action
bbbb    2/8/14  email
bbbb    2/9/14  email
bbbb    2/10/14 won
dddd    2/3/14  email
dddd    3/3/14  won
```

So basically, by email, if "won" occurs in the Action column first, I want to get rid of all observations associated with that email. However, if there are other Actions preceding the first "won" observation for a given email I want to keep the data (including the row where the "won" is observed) and everything that occurred before it. Dataset A contains the first observed "won" for each email. Dataset B contains everything else and all the wins.

I've tried using `sqldf`, but it's not working exactly right. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is not clear the role of the two datasets. The results might be achieve with `datasetB` only. it is a little bit redundant and not clear what does it needed `datasetA`.

Comment: Yeah, I thought I might be able to use `sqldf` to join the two, but I realize I can probably just select from `datasetB`. I'm just not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure what you need the first data for, here's an attempt using `data.table` only on your second data which works fine

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)[, if(Action[1L] != "won") .SD[seq_len(match("won", Action))], by = Email]
#    Email    Date Action
# 1:  bbbb  2/8/14  email
# 2:  bbbb  2/9/14  email
# 3:  bbbb 2/10/14    won
# 4:  dddd  2/3/14  email
# 5:  dddd  3/3/14    won
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! Thank you @DavidArenburg for the `data.table` solution. I always enjoy learning what else that package can do.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one with base R.  In addition, this approach could be easily adopted to SQL.

```
DatasetB<-as.Date(DatesetB, "%m/%d/%Y")
DatasetA<-as.Date(DatesetA, "%m/%d/%Y")
ans <- merge(DatasetB , DatasetA, by="Email")
ans <- ans[ans$Date.x<=ans$Date.y, ]
ans <- ans[duplicated(ans$Email) | duplicated(ans$Email, fromLast=TRUE),]  #removing email's with one won
```

Comment: You will probably need to convert to proper `Date` classes in order for this to work potentially

Comment: Your formatting is wrong... It should be `DatasetB$Date<-as.Date(DatasetB$Date, "%m/%d/%y");DatasetA$Date<-as.Date(DatasetA$Date, "%m/%d/%y")`. And you have some other syntax issues. But ones you fix them, your answer reaches the desired output.

Comment: Now the `ans <- D[ans$Date.x<=ans$Date.y, ]` part... :)

Comment: Haha, that is what I get for not testing in R first.  Thanks David!

Answer (score 2):

This worked when I ran it on your Dataset B as df:

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- slice(group_by(filter(merge(df, summarise(group_by(df, Email), first = first(Action)), all.x=TRUE), first!= "won")[,1:3], Email), 1:match("won", Action))
```

It's easier to follow with the steps broken out:

```
df_grouped <- group_by(df, Email)
dfsum <- summarise(df_grouped, first = first(Action))
df2 <- merge(df, dfsum, all.x=TRUE)
df3 <- filter(df2, first!= "won")[,1:3]
df4 <- group_by(df3, Email)
df5 <- slice(df4, 1:match("won", Action))
```

Which suggests using the piping operator provided by 'dplyr':

```
df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(Email) %>%
  summarise(first = first(Action)) %>%
  inner_join(df, .) %>%
  filter(first!="won") %>%
  group_by(Email) %>%
  slice(1:match("won", Action)) %>%
  select(-first)
```

Comment: Your code isn't returning the desired output. Please compare it to the output provided by the OP

Comment: Are you referring to the added column? If so, I just edited to trim that from the result.

Comment: No, Please provide your output and count the **rows** you have compared to the desired output. Just writing `library(dplyr)` without showing what your code is actually doing doesn't always work.

Comment: Oh, wait, now I see the issue: she wants rows only up to the first "won". I misread it as all rows associated with any winners. I will try to correct that.